# How to pass value from html file to views.py file?

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

after user enter 10 digits number automatically python function will call. i need to send text box value to python function (views.py). How to get value in views.py?

i don't want when user click on submit button to get value in text box.

> base.html

```
  <input type="text" name="vat" id="vat1" placeholder="Please Enter 10 digits number">
```

> script

```
var Value = document.getElementById('vat1').value;
alert(Value);
```

> views.py

```
def call_operator(request):
    text_box_value = request.POST.get('vat')
    print(text_box_value)
    print("get operator name and circle name")
    template_name = 'mobile_recharge.html'
    extended_template = 'base.html'
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        extended_template = 'base_login.html'
    return render(
        request, template_name,
        {'extended_template': extended_template}
    )
```

> urls.py

```
url(r'^call_operator/$', call_operator)
```

> script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#vat1').keyup(function(){
            if ($(this).val().length == 10){
                $('your_form').submit();
                 alert("condition satisfied");
             $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:8090/call_operator/"
                    });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> html file

```
          <form method="POST" role="form" name="your_form">
              <input type="text" name="vat" id="vat1" placeholder="Please Enter 10 digits number">
         </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax. This is other way to do it

base.html

```
<form method="POST" name="your_form" action="{% url 'your_app:your_url' %}">
    <input type="text" name="vat" id="vat1" placeholder="Please Enter 10 digits number">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#vat1').keyup(function(event){
            if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13){
                if ($(this).val().length == 10){
                    $('your_form').submit();
                }else{
                    // Show message if the text length is lesser than 10
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: counter is not good idea. user can use backspace, etc.
if ('#vat1').val().length == 10

Comment: getting text box value None: def call_operator(request):
    text_box_value = request.POST.get('vat')
    print(text_box_value)

Comment: Please share your views.py, urls.py and the template complete!

Comment: You got some errors : First, you're not setting the data dictionary for the ajax request, secondly you're sending ajax request via GET and the function receives via POST, last, you're doing a submit to the form but you didn't create it inside the form...actually you don't need a form if you use ajax.

Comment: getting value but one problem is there after enter 10 digits and then press enter only form is submitting. it's not submit automatically when user enter 10 digits. how to solve that?